# Socket.io correct way to save user sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Okay so i am playing around with `Socket.io` and creating costum "chat" rooms for my users. for this purpose i have created the following object:

```
    function MentorRoom(room_id, organization_id, roomname, is_private, creator) {
    this.activeUsers = [];
    this.room_id = room_id;
    this.organization_id = organization_id;
    this.roomName = roomname;
    this.is_private = is_private;
    this.creator = creator;
}

MentorRoom.prototype.appendUser = function (user) {
    this.activeUsers.push(user)
};
MentorRoom.prototype.removeUser = function (user) {
    this.activeUsers.splice(this.activeUsers.indexOf(user), 1);
};
MentorRoom.prototype.containUser = function (user) {
    return this.activeUsers.indexOf(user) >= 0;
};
```

This allows me to create `MentorRoom` objects.

When creating one of these rooms it might look abit something like this:

```
this.createRoom = function (room, user) {
    var id = mentorRooms.length + 1;
    var newRoom = new MentorRoom(id, room.organization_id, room.name, room.is_private, user);
    newRoom.appendUser(user);
    mentorRooms.push(newRoom);
    return id;
};
```

Now the user in this case also contains a `socket` object so that i later will be able to `emit` to that `socket`. for instance when another user joins

However this creates a few issues!

For instance if i wish to send my room list to another client (so that he can see which available rooms there are) i would do it like so:

```
socket.emit('updateRoomList', rooms);
```

However since each room contains a variable (`creator`) that also contains a socket i get the following error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This problem will persist with the architecture i have right now because when ever i add a user to the list of `activeUsers` in the room i also need their socket so i can send messages directly to each individual users.

So my question is how do you store and send variables that contains a `Socket` object.

Comment: In most cases, you can just use the socket.id.  No need to save the whole socket object.

Comment: @Gary How do i use it later then? if i wish to emit to that user / socket id

Comment: io.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');